# Definition of gravitational potential energy. WITHOUT Acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, work, potential-energy

Gravitational potential energy is defined in the textbook as the amount of work done in bringing a mass from infinity to that point in gravitational field without producing acceleration.

What does 'without producing acceleration' imply?

Comment: “Gravitational potential energy is defined....Without producing acceleration”. I have never heard the definition worded this way. Provide a link to that definition.

Answer (score 0):

It means you want to start the process and end the process with the same kinetic energy.  That way any work done must have gone into changing the potential energy of the system and not into the KE of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If the mass accelerates, then the work gives the mass both kinetic energy and gravitational potential energy, not just gravitational potential energy.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration doesn't actually need to be zero. As long as the speed of the mass before you start moving is equal to the speed after you are done moving it, the work you have done has resulted in no change of kinetic energy of the mass, so the potential energy change is still equal to this work.